# Moses' birth story, divine oversight or another trick? Exodus 2

Tags: moses, miracle

Exodus 2:2-6 relates the story of Moses's birth, placement in the ark by his mother and sister, and subsequent discovery by pharaoh's daughter.

This story clearly fits two thematic biblical patterns:

1. birth stories of the the forefathers, prophets and judges
2. divine oversight and intervention

However, this story also contains a ruse, a trick. So, is this story purely a continuation of the theme of divine intervention in history from the end of Genesis, about Josephs's sale into bondage and subsequent rise to power, or does this story have elements of the tradition of tricks in

1. Jacob buying Esau's birthright
2. Rebekah convincing Jacob to trick Isaac of Esau's blessing
3. Jacob tricking Laban
4. Rachel stealing her father's idols
5. The sons of Jacob's deception of Schem and Hamor
6. Peretz's birth
7. Tamar's deception of Judah

**Are there signs in the language of the text itself** that this story could also be part of the tradition of tricks and deceptions practiced in the house of Jacob? Does this passage make a different statement about ruses and tricks than the previous passages cited above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was nothing miraculous about Moses' birth.  His mother conceived in the usual fashion.  The only comment about Moses is made in Ex 2:2 -

> and she conceived and gave birth to a son. When she saw that he was a
> **beautiful child**, she hid him for three months.

The premise for this hiding for 3 month was because of the royal decree that all male children must be drowned by throwing them in the Nile river (Ex 1:28).

The subtlety in the story is that Moses' mother decided to comply with this requirement with a twist (a "set-up") aimed at achieving the opposite effect of the royal decree's intention, to save the baby's life by tugging at the heart-strings (Ex 2:6) of pharaoh's daughter, who apparently had no children.

[**Side note**: Whatever chronology one uses for the dating the story of Moses, archeology tells us that the Egyptian royal families were incestuous, and as a result, did not live long because of delicate health and numerous diseases. Further, infertility of royal women was also common.  By contrast, the Hebrew women were "vigorous" (Ex 1:19) and lived longer and healthier lives and reproduced readily and copiously.  Thus, a Hebrew child would have been desirable as an Egyptian adoptive.]

Thus it was by the cunning of Jocabed that Moses' life was saved as follows:

- Moses was "thrown" in the Nile, but with a little boat to prevent him drowning
- the place where Moses was placed in the river was deliberately near where pharaoh's daughter bathed
- the thinly disguised ruse (which the princess almost certainly understood immediately) was designed to have Moses adopted by the princess
- the services of a wet nurse were offered by the near-by and watching Miriam.  Again, this was a pretense which the princes would have understood to maintain a fig-leaf of credibility and respectability.

Thus, while this was a cunning ruse, I do not believe for a moment that the princess was deceived - she must have known what was going on but played along for her own benefit - she recognized the child as a Hebrew child! (Heb 2:6.)  [Again, archeological records show that because of the endemic fertility problems in Egyptian families (due to poor health and incest) adoption was common.]

Lastly, the princess even named the child, "Moses" which is probably a reference to her "drawing out" the child from the river Nile.  That is, the name was Hebrew in sound but Egyptian in origin and had a royal "ring" to it. ["Moses" or a slight variation was contained in many of the pharaoh's names, such as Ahmose, Kahmose, Ramases, Thutmose, etc, etc.]

**Notes about "Ruses"**

Generally, we may classify a ruse as either:

- deceptive - a ruse that is designed to deceive and gain a personal advantage, is clearly immoral and unethical and invariably damaging.
- "harmless"; while any ruse is by its very nature deceptive to some extent, these latter types are do not necessarily cause harm but are often used to minimize or eliminate harm.  See the appendix below.

The ruse of Moses' mother to protect his life by saving him from the king's decree, was clearly designed in such a way as not to cause any harm, but to prevent it.  Further, very little, if any, deception was involved because the princess must have been fully aware of what was going on but played along with the "game" to save the baby Moses' life.

Whether this ruse was divine directed as in the case of the prophet Samuel (1 Sam 16:1-3), we are not told; however, the tenor and importance of the story makes it appear that it was at least part of God's providence.

**APPENDIX - Lying**

Lying, or spreading what is untrue, or bearing false witness, are acts forbidden by the ninth commandment (Ex 20:16) and many other places (Lev 19:11, Ps 34:13, 58:3, 101:7, 109:2, Prov 6:16-19, 12:19, 14:5, 19:5, 9, 21:6, 24:28, Matt 15:18-20, 1 Cor 6:9-11, Eph 4:25, Col 3:9, 10, Rev 21:8, etc.)  However, there were times when an ethical dilemma arises where lying was the lesser of two evils.

- Jeremiah – Jer 38:24-27
- Jericho spies – Josh 2:1 (spying, by nature, is an enacted lie.)
- Rahab of Jericho – Josh 2:2-7
- Samuel – 1 Sam 16:1-3
- Hushai the Arkite – 2 Sam 15:32-37, 16:15-19
- Woman at Bahurim – 2 Sam 17:17-20
- Michal protecting David – 1 Sam 19:11-17
- David – 1 Sam 21:1-9, 12-15
- Prophet – 1 Kings 13:18
- Jehu – 2 Kings 10:10, 19, 30

The fact that some lied in order to protect life clearly says that life had, in some cases, a greater value than truth.

Comment: Do you think that the story of this ruse is included in the text is part of the tradition of ruses and tricks in Genesis? What linguistic or thematic links are there between the previous ruses and this one? What statement about ruses is Exodus 2 making?

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahimalYahud - one could classify two types of ruses - harmless and deceptive.  The latter deceives does harm with a view to embezzlement in some form.  However, "harmless ruses" do not really deceive - the princess say through this immediately and was not deceived.  Thus, the Exodus ruse was a different kind from the Genesis ruses.

Comment: So add that to your answer.

Comment: I think that a key difference in this case there is that there is no actual deception, only a ruse that happened to play on the emotions of a young woman. If you agree, then I think that this point should be the main point of your answer. Another distinction, in the other cases, a specific desired outcome was predictable by the perpetrator in advance, whereas in this case the outcome, Moses' mission, was not and could not have been predicted. A third possibility is that the story of Moses in the ark is intended to show how a act of pure desperation turned into salvation by divine intervention.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahimalYahud - while I agree with most of what you suggest here, that is difficult to deduce directly from the narrative at hand, Moses and the Nile.  I have listed above about all that I believe can be deduced directly from the narrative and that not real deception was involved.

Comment: Reluctantly approved as the answer. I think that the differences between the deceptions at the thematic level are clear from the text at the thematic level, and that the narrative in Genesis 2 is not part of the earlier tradition of deceptions that are related WRT the patriarchs and Jacob's sons.

Answer (score 2):

If one misses the spiritual reasons for Rebekah enquiring of the Lord (Isaac did not) ; for Rebekah helping Jacob (Isaac liked his venison and his hunting son) ; for Jacob wanting the blessing which was promised when he was in the womb (Esau despised it all) ; for Jacob seeking a Providential blessing (Laban treated him like a slave) ; and for Tamar sitting by a roadside (when denied her rights by Judah) then, yes, you may imagine all sorts of things about these people.

There is no 'trick' at all. They saw things which others did not. And they believed in One who is invisible. *That* is the 'trick'.

They sought God's purposes (which would culminate in Messiah coming to earth).

The people who did not seek such, did not, in the end, prosper.

Comment: So its fine to tell lies if you believe it to serve God's purpose? It that what these stories are teaching us?

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahimalYahud I don't see any lies. But then I am not seeing things the way you see them. I see spiritual truth. And the promises of God (which are true). These people saw spiritual realities and they worked towards those realities. Tamar just sat by a roadside. Jacob said he was Esau (which he was, for he had - legitimately - taken Esau's place). As I said, I don't see things the way you seem to be seeing them.

Comment: Hmm.. That's a very unique position. Are there any mainstream commentators who say that Abram wasn't speaking deceptively (lying actually) when he told Pharaoh that Sarai was his sister rather than his wife, or Abraham and Avimeleck, or Isaac and Avimeleck? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wife%E2%80%93sister_narratives_in_the_Book_of_Genesis

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahimalYahud Sarah was, indeed, Abraham's sister. She was his half sister. This is made clear by Abraham himself in the Genesis text. But it is easy to criticise when one lives in a civilised country and is not under threat of death at a moment's notice if a ruler spies one's wife and can kill one without a blink to get one's wife. Those were barbaric times. But even so, Abraham told the truth.